# Target a path element that only has 'd' attribute with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hello im learning some web scraping with selenium. I have a map with svg hexagons drawn on it and i want to click on a hexagon so that it gets the value for that hexagon. The problem is, as far as i can tell, the hexagons are only unique in their `d` attribute. How can i target such an  element?

This is what i get when i inspect the element

```
<path class="hexbin-hexagon" d="M-230016.3472451469,-150000m0,-400l346.41016151377545,199.99999999999994l5.684341886080802e-14,400l-346.41016151377545,200.00000000000009l-346.4101615137754,-199.99999999999983l-2.8421709430404007e-13,-399.9999999999999z" fill="rgb(125, 145, 72)" fill-opacity="0.6" stroke-opacity="0.6"></path>
```

And this is the map
https://sofia.maps.sensor.community/#11/47.4410/13.9749

EDIT: Im posting the code i have so far

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "/home/pex/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://sofia.maps.sensor.community/#11/47.4410/13.9749")



hexagon = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//path[@d="M562.9165124598851,300m0,-25l21.650635094610966,12.499999999999996l3.552713678800501e-15,25l-21.650635094610966,12.500000000000005l-21.650635094610962,-12.49999999999999l-1.7763568394002505e-14,-24.999999999999993z"]')
```

EDIT 2: Ok this is strange but my browser cant seem to find any elements with path, even when I try finding any elements that have a `d` attribute [image: screenshot chrome dev tools]

EDIT 3: I think my pc is not able to process this query for some reason. //path doesnt return anything as well.

Comment: What do you want to do with the target element?

Comment: Oh man this site seems to bust my browser! The elements are there int he DOM but inspect element struggles to find them. Seems over 6000 path elements... I wonder if you're hitting some sort of limit.

Comment: in theory if you just want to select path elements that HAVE any d value this would work: //path[@d]

Comment: @DebanjanB I just want to have the value from the graph that is presented when you click on the element

Comment: @5ko.brat What happens when you try to click them? Any error?

Comment: @DebanjanB no if I click them in the browser everything is normal i get a table and i can inspect it too

Comment: @5ko.brat Which `<path>` element are you targeting?

Comment: @DebanjanB it doesnt matter any would do but i cant find any element by xpath even when i cope the xpath of a `<path>` and paste it im going to start a new thread to aks why

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
//path[@d="M-230016.3472451469,-150000m0,-400l346.41016151377545,199.99999999999994l5.684341886080802e-14,400l-346.41016151377545,200.00000000000009l-346.4101615137754,-199.99999999999983l-2.8421709430404007e-13,-399.9999999999999z"]
```

Xpath syntax is tag[@attribut="value"] so you can use the above one

[image]

Comment: I did just now but if returned an exception Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: Try it in console first then try it I'm script

Comment: i did try it in the console but again it failed

Comment: @5ko.brat it should work , i added the screen shot .  it showing zero elements in console ?

Comment: @PDHide It's not showing `zero` elements but **`one`** element.

Comment: It was a question

Comment: @PDHide Yes i think my pc is just too slow to process this. The //path query also doesn't return  anything even //meta only returned some value after i refreshed multiple times. I tested //path on my other pc and still no result though.